# Radix sorting for pairs of numbers

Tags: algorithms, radix-sort

I'm struggling with implementing  **O(n+k) radix sorting algorithm** for pairs of numbers which values are constrained .

For example
below is array of {x,y} before and after using modified radix sort where max_x=10 and max_y=3

```
{1,2}        {1,1}
{10,3}       {1,2}
{1,1}  ----> {5,2}
{5,2}        {5,3}
{5,3}        {10,3}
```

How I should modify standrad radix sort to be possible of sorting it?I would be thankful for pseudo code.

I need it to improve time complexity of data structure based on Karp-Miller-Rosenberg algorithm , which could provide me O(nlogn) , better than O(nlog^2n) which you would get by using quick sorting. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you're asking.  I don't know what you mean by "sorting algorithm for pairs of numbers which values are constrained".  Please [edit] your question to clarify what your specific question is.  I don't see a question here.  A question normally ends with a "?".  Implementation in C++ is off-topic here.

Comment: I edited. I hope now is understandable